# Key authentication not working when using ssh or rsync as sudo

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, rsync, password, sudo

I have ssh RSA key authentication setup between a client and an ubuntu server ([following this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys)):
-the RSA key authentication for `ssh` and `rsync` work fine (no need for password).
-the RSA key authentication for `sudo rsync` and `sudo ssh` fails (I'm prompted for a password).
-I need to use `sudo rsync` to write the remote files locally.

I'm running the command as follows:

```
user1@server:/$ sudo su user2
user2@server:/$ rsync 192.168.1.2:... # ok
user2@server:/$ sudo rsync 192.168.1.2:... # remote host password prompt
```

FYI both **user1** and **user2** are part of sudoers

Any idea where that could be coming from?

Thanks.

**updated:** to clarify, the password prompt is not coming from sudo but from the server

Comment: Are you being asked for a password for sudo or rsync?  I suspect sudo (in the absence of other information), which means you would have to add the sudo command with NOPASSWD: to sudoers.

Comment: It looks like an environment issue. Try running `su - user` The - will cause you to inherit the users environment. Alternatively you could specify the path to the key file : something like rsync -e ssh -i /home/user2/.ssh/private.key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell it to use the correct public key.  I suspect ssh is still using user1's key, not user2.  Use this command:

```
sudo -u user2 ssh -i ~user2/.ssh/id_rsa remoteserver
```

I tested this on my machine and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is in

```
#/etc/sudoers
====at the end of file add this====
user1 ALL = NOPASSWD:ALL
```

this will remove password promt for user1 using sudo command.

dont forget that sudo users may store they ssh keys in /root/.ssh/ and not in /home/user1/.ssh/